# The java command works but i didn't set the java environment

Tags: java

I installed java 7.0 on centos with RPM package and didn't set the java environment, but the command java -version, java, javac works fine. I searched on web site, they said we need to export the java environment, but i did't do it and java works. Is that correct?

Comment: yes your package manager set enviroment

Answer (score 0):

That is the normal behaviour if you install Java using a package manager.

The package manager creates a symbolic link from `/usr/bin/java` to the correct destination.

You can change this symbolic link by using the command `alternatives`.

Also current installations of Java are smart enough to find the rest of the installation if it is a proper installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I am still not understand that why the system can recognize the java commands even if I didn't set the environment. Since the system could recognize the java command, so i think there must be somewhere has the java destination configured. And the system could find the Java home. 

But when i start the tomcat(installed with tar), the tomcat start log shows the jre home is /usr, not the correct path and with no error. But i could not access http://localhost:8080

Comment: And i used the command alternatives --display java, nothing displayed